# Published android app only displays default android logo when installed

Tags: android, icons, publish

I created a simple android app in android studio. I have a logo that shows up just fine when launching the app in the emulator on android studio, testing multiple emulators. I even built an APK and installed it on my phone, and again the logo worked just fine. Now that the app is published, it only shows the default android logo.

I used Image Asset Studio for Adaptive/Legacy.

Note: I'm not referring to the Play Store display, that image is uploaded separately and is appearing as it should. I'm referring to the app icon when it's installed.

Any insight?

I went back to android studio after the app was published to see if anything was inadvertently changed before publishing, and no changes were made.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Turns out when I added the logo, I did not add it to the release version. I added it to the debug version only.

Still very new at this, so always learning.